# Validation of text Field

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I'm trying to validate my text field with rang limit of 5 and also not allow to insert only 0 value on starting character and i also want to restrict my text field with special character ,below is my code  my two function  range limit and  starting character 0 accepted are working fine but restrication of special character is not working can you please suggest me  what's the problem??

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
    replacementString:(NSString *)string  {

                [self isNumeric:textField.text];

                NSUInteger newLength = [textField.text length] + [string length] - range.length;

                if (range.location == 0 && [string isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
                    return NO;
                 }
                return (newLength > 5) ? NO : YES;

        }


-(BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString*)inputString{

    NSCharacterSet *cs = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:ACCEPTABLE_NUMBERS] invertedSet];
    NSString *filtered = [[inputString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:cs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
    return [inputString isEqualToString:filtered];
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer. Check it and let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is to limit 5 numeric letters but 0 can not be the first number:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string{
    NSString *resultStr = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if([self isNumeric:resultStr]){
        if(resultStr.length <= 5){
             if(resultStr.length >= 1){
                  NSString *firstLetter = [resultStr substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];
                  if(![firstLetter isEqualToString:@"0"]){
                      return YES;
                  }
             }
             else{
                  return YES;
             }
        }
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not evaluate the `BOOL` coming from `[self isNumeric:textField.text];`, therefore you are just filtering the length- and 0-conditions.

Add an extra if-statement to solve this problem:

```
if (![self isNumeric:textField.text]) {
    return NO;
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following code and let me know it will help or not:-

```
    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([self isNumeric:string])
    {
        if([textField.text length]==0 && [string length]==1 && [string isEqualToString:@"0"])
        {
            return NO;
        }

        if([textField.text length]==5 && ![string isEqualToString:@""])
            return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}

-(BOOL)isNumeric:(NSString*)inputString{
    NSCharacterSet *acceptableCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: ACCEPTABLE_NUMBERS];

    unichar c = [self getLastAddedStringAsCharacter:inputString];

    if ([acceptableCharacterSet characterIsMember:c]){
        return YES;
    }
    else if ([inputString isEqualToString:@""]){
        return YES;
    }
    else{
        return NO;
    }
}

-(unichar)getLastAddedStringAsCharacter:(NSString *)lastStr{
    if ([lastStr length]>0){
        return [lastStr characterAtIndex:0];
    }
    else{
        return '\0';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check This One

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *currentString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    int length = [currentString length];
    if (length > 5) {
        return NO;
    }
    else if ([textField.text  isEqual: @"0"]){
        return N);
    }
    return YES;
}
```